Chromium (snap) on Xubuntu 24.04 : "Password Manager needs more access"
I upgraded from Xubuntu LTS 22.04 to 24.04, and I'm getting this annoying Password Manager needs more access message in chromium now (installed via snap, and up-to-date):

Of course, clicking Relaunch Chromium relaunches the browser, but doesn't fix the problem (the same popup reappears endlessly), and I cannot access my saved passwords.
What am I missing there ?
EDIT: could the downvoter explain what is wrong with my question ? Thanks ;)

This is a question you ask the maker of the password manager. Is their app working with Ubuntu 24.04?

My system password manager is seahorse, but I don't know what chromium uses under the hood ...

I have the same problem with a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 install (on a new device). I have used rsync to copy my old home directory (Ubuntu 22.04) to the new device.

New hint: When launching from the common line, I get a series of error messages: ERROR:login_database.cc(1047)] Password decryption failed, encryption_result is 2. Unfortunately that has not led me to a solution yet.

A workaround is to delete the old passwords in chrome://password-manager/passwords and save them again : annoying, but the popup disappeared ...

My old passowrds are not listed there. Instead I have a similar message there, about relaunching Chromium for more access.
